# Marker icon not showing up but is clickable

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've got the following code which gets information from a database and plots it on a map. The information is there and clickable but the actual icon `androidmarker` is not visable. Why? How do I fix this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tweets = new LocationData(this);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mc = mapView.getController();

    mc.setZoom(17);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    // Add the MyPositionOverlay
    positionOverlay = new MyPositionOverlay();
    List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    overlays.add(positionOverlay);

    //Add the Mapitems Overlay.

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    itemizedoverlay = new Mapitems(drawable, this);

    mylocation();
    distance(lat,lng);
    addmark();
    mapView.invalidate();
}

public void addmark(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = tweets.getWritableDatabase();
    String count = "SELECT * FROM tweets;";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    startManagingCursor(mcursor);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();  
    if(mcursor != null && mcursor.moveToFirst())
    {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("WHAT");
            String tname = mcursor.getString(4);
            String tmessage = mcursor.getString(7);
            Double tlat = mcursor.getDouble(1);
            System.out.println("lat" + tlat);
            Double tlng = mcursor.getDouble(2);
            System.out.println("lng" + tlng);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (tlat*1E6),
                    (int) (tlng*1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, tname, tmessage);
            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


            }while(mcursor.moveToNext());

    }
}
```

Comment: are tlat and tlng pixels on the screen or geopoints? It looks like they aren't geopoints and you need to use Map Projection to map between (x,y) and (lat,lng)

Comment: They are plotted correctly. When I click on that point on the screen where its meant to be the popup box shows up. Its just there's no icon there to identify it visibly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Mapitems is the class that is implementing ItemizedOverlay.
The problem is probably there.You can follow the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) on how to create that class properly. I've followed this tutorial myself and it worked fine for me.  The important part is to make sure you call `populate()` after you add the overlay in `addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)`

Also, why do you have `mapOverlays` and `overlays`? Aren't they the same?

Comment: I am following that tutorial. I had it working too but now that I'm doing it within a loop it's not showing icons. I've got both just because that's the way I happened to code 2 different Overlays.

Comment: Is the popup box an event of the overlay or you added different markers some place else? Because if you say that it used to work the only logical thing would be that the locations aren't correct